# Camel Spring RabbitMQ component: at least one semantic

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-amqp

Can Spring RabbitMQ component be configured to guarantee "at least once" delivery when I consume the message from one rabbit cluster and publish it to another one?

For example for rabbitMQ component we have the following scope of parameters:

```
auto-ack: false
mandatory: true
guaranteed-deliveries: true
publisher-acknowledgments: true
reQueue: true
```

How I can configure Spring RabbitMQ component to reach the same guarantee?

Is only the way to reach this is to add custom ExceptionHandler to send "nack" and send "ack" for a successful case on some processor at the end of my route?